# Crosstab in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, crosstab

I'm trying to pivot a table in Postgres. My table 'sample' has many columns (code, sector, concept, year, period, value, preorder), instead of having 1 concept, 1 year, 1 value per row, i want the concept with values by year.

```
Select * from crosstab('Select concept, year, value from sample_table
    Where code=1800
    AND period='Annual'
    AND Sector='Agro'
    Order by year,preorder;
    ',
    $$VALUES ('2009'::int), ('2010'), ('2011'), ('2012'), ('2013'), ('2014')$$)
AS value("concept" varchar(255),"2009" int, "2010" int, "2011" int, "2012" int, "2013" int, "2014" int);
```

First I had an error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "Annual"
LINE 3:  AND period='Annual'
```

Then when I replaced the single quotes by double quotes I got:

```
ERROR:  column "Annual" does not exist
LINE 3:  AND period="Annual"
                         ^
```

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Second question would be, does anyone know how to generate the column names dynamically, ie instead of hard coding the years, maybe, do a select distinct on the relevant column?

Comment: Your inner quotes are not properly escaped. Try surrounding the statement with `$$` instead of `'`. Double quotes are not like single quotes in SQL; they're exclusively used for quoting identifiers (column names, table names, etc.) and not for strings.

Comment: Thx, it seems most examples I have seen were using single quotes in the inner query, but they didn't have to escape query attributes, as there were none. It triggered another problem, so will post another SO question.